# How can I resolve this error in the flutter package google_mobile_ads

Tags: android, flutter, google-mobile-ads

I am trying to configure my app to show test ads but when I run the app in the android emulator it crashes and I get this error:

```
 /Users/me/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_mobile_ads-0.13.2/lib/src/ad_containers.dart:454:9: Error: A value of type 'Type' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
 - 'Type' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
        ErrorSummary,
        ^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Volumes/macex/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Volumes/macex/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 56s
```

I am using :

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.2.3 20D91 darwin-x64, locale en-CA)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Thanks!

Comment: From error log my understanding is, 

> `A value of type 'Type' can't be assigned to a variable of type
> 'DiagnosticsNode'`

somewhere in the code there is a type casting problem occurs.  It is expecting the value of type `DiagnosticsNode` but provided with the `Type` type.

Answer (score 0):

I had ran the example project from https://github.com/googlecodelabs/admob-inline-ads-in-flutter
which used google_mobile_ads version 0.13.0, while my app used version 0.13.2.

So maybe some sort of conflict was going on, so I deleted both versions of google_mobile_ads-0.13.* from .pub-cache and then ran `flutter clean` and then re-downloaded the packages and updated both apps to use the same 0.13.2 version.

Now it seems to be working.